# access an IP restricted service from a dynamic IP (Broadband modem) on a windows machine

Tags: windows-7, remote-access, static-ip

I dont know if this is the correct place to ask this question but here goes ..

(please note that I am pretty much a newbie in terms of networking and I work primarily on the  windows platform)

I have been working on accessing and consuming some web services in C#/ASP.Net, these web services that I consume are IP restricted. Currently they allow access only from my work network (we have a static ip set up through which all our internet requests are routed).

Every now and then we have people who go out and about and are stuck with using a usb dongle based internet connection and hence are not able to now access these web services that they are working on.

What I would like to do is to provide some way for these remote workers to access the IP restricted web services using the static ip at our office. For example when the remote worker tries to access a service say http://exampleService.com .. the request gets routed to some box at our office and then out to the actual service. That way the service always sees the static ip of the office and not the dynamic ip that the remote user is actually using.

I have done a fair bit of googling and its difficult to search for it as most of the results come back for dynamic DNS which is not really what I am looking for.

I have also looked at a couple of posts on here namely 
https://serverfault.com/questions/187231/accessing-ip-restricted-server-from-dynamic-ip
which does provide some insight but the fellow seems to have access to the source that does the ip restriction and is able to change the restrictions. In my case i dont have that access.
another one that looked interesting was 
 https://serverfault.com/questions/136806/static-ip-for-dynamic-ip
the first answer seems exactly what I need but I dont know how I would go about on a windows machine.

any help would be really appreciated. (am sorry about being soo noob-ish)

PS: Right now everyone is using RDC/LogMeIn to access an internet connected machine in the office to manually check the webservice and getting work done. Which is a very tedious process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should look at the users VPN'ing into the office network. This would give them an IP address in your office range and allow them to access the software. There are all sorts of VPN software solutions out there, which one you choose depends on your needs / budget. We used a hardware setup using the [Zyxel SSL10](http://www.zyxel.co.uk/web/news_news.php?sqno=467) but it can also be done with software.